What does the "ECMA Script" project setting in TMS WEB Core do?
In the project settings, you're able to set "ECMA Script" between nothing, "ECMA Script 5" and "ECMA Script 6".

But I'm really confused as to what this actually does. I've tried all three settings and my output JavaScript code is exactly the same regardless of the setting.
These are the new things in "ECMA Script 6":


The let keyword
The const keyword
Arrow Functions
The ... Operator
For/of
Map Objects
Set Objects
Classes
Promises
Symbol
Default Parameters
Function Rest Parameter
String.includes()
String.startsWith()
String.endsWith()
Array.from()
Array keys()
Array find()
Array findIndex()
New Math Methods
New Number Properties
New Number Methods
New Global Methods
Object entries
JavaScript Modules


But I don't really see any of this in my output code when set to "ECMA Script 6".

As an example, here is some Delphi programming code:
procedure TFrame_404PageNotFound.WebFrameResize(Sender: TObject);
const
  TestingConstant: String = 'Hello World!';
var
  TestingSomething: String;
  I: UInt64;
begin
  For I := 0 to 10 do
    TestingSomething := 'Hello World!';
  console.log('TFrame_404PageNotFound.WebFrameResize');
end;

And this is the output JavaScript for it:
var TestingConstant = "Hello World!";
this.WebFrameResize = function (Sender) {
  var TestingSomething = "";
  var I = 0;
  for (I = 0; I <= 10; I++) TestingSomething = "Hello World!";
  window.console.log("TFrame_404PageNotFound.WebFrameResize");
};

I would have expected for the code to be turned into something more ES6 like when "ECMA Script 6" is selected. Something like this:
const TestingConstant = "Hello World!";
this.WebFrameResize = (Sender) => {
  let TestingSomething = "";
  for (let I = 0; I <= 10; I++) TestingSomething = "Hello World!";
  window.console.log("TFrame_404PageNotFound.WebFrameResize");
};


So what does the "ECMA Script" setting actually do? What are the differences between "ECMA Script 5" and "ECMA Script 6" in the Project Options?
Because as far as I can see, my output JavaScript is exactly the same regardless of my "ECMA Script" setting.

Your best bet is to contact TMS Support.

The var/const difference is probably because in Delphi, a typed constant isn't (necessarily) (constant). Depedning on a compiler directive, you may modify a typed constant in code. So if the Pas2js cross-compiler translates it as you'd suspect, it would encounter an error when you later on tried to update the typed constant TestingConstant.

I don't have much familiarity with TMS Web Core, but after delving into it briefly, I stumbled upon some valuable insights. TMS Web Core employs Pas2js to convert Pascal-written programs into JavaScript. According to the official Pas2js documentation, it utilizes ECMA Script 5 as the default JavaScript version, which should alleviate any concerns regarding translation without a specified version.
Regarding the ECMA Script 6 version, I encountered limited information, specifically:

ECMAScript6: introducing 0b for binary literals and 0o for octal literals.

I've formulated two theories based on this snippet: either the ECMAScript 6 translator solely incorporates these changes, or there might be an issue with TMS Web Core's integration of Pas2js.
For further details, you can explore the following link:
Pas2js Transpiler Wiki
